# TCP-Connection - keep up or reconnect?

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I have a general question regarding TCP-IP communication...

for the time being I try to create a small communication between an ATMega and a Raspberry Pi. I will transmit some data for example every 5 minutes (e.g. 100 byte) via TCP/IP Protocol.

Does it make sense to keep the connection open or shall I create a new connection for each dataset?

Thanks for your help...

webbolle

Comment: Keep it up for as long as you can, but be prepared to reconnect on failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would lean towards keeping the TCP connection open rather than opening a new one everytime.

Here are a few reasons. First, by using the same connection, you would save on not having to send TCP handshake message (SYN-based messages) and teardown messages (FIN-based messages). In your case, if you are going to transmit 100 bytes every 5 minutes, the overhead of SYN/FIN messages might be more than that. Second, if you already have the connection open, then you would save on time since there is no need to do the reconnection. Third, TCP might go to slow-start every time you start the connection -- should not be a problem with 100 bytes, but if you need to send more bytes, then with every new connection, TCP would start its send window with 1 MSS. But, if you reuse an existing connection, TCP would (probably) use the current window.

Also:
An open connection doesn't consume any resources (bandwith etc.) except for the ports it holds on both devices. Basically every TCP-connection that has been opened and not been closed is still open, save unintended disconnections etc.
For detecting those is also doesn't make a difference wether you keep open or reopen:
If the connection dropped out in the meantime you'll receive the more or less same error.